# Dereferncing a pointer doesn't return the real value in the memory address

Tags: c, pointers, memory, embedded

I'm developing an embedded application on `STM8S` using `STVD` IDE and `Cosmic C` compiler. I'm trying to read FLASH memory byte by byte to calculate `CRC`. Following is my code snippet:

```
uint32_t crc32_buffer(const uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len)
{
    uint32_t index = 0;
    uint32_t crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    uint32_t flashIndex = 0;
    uint8_t *ptr = buf;
    volatile uint8_t value = 0;
    volatile uint8_t i = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < len; index++)
    {
        value = *ptr;
        flashIndex = (crc & 0xFF) ^ value;
        ptr++;
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ table[flashIndex];

        if(bytesCntr >= 2685)
        {
           i++;
        }
    }

    return ~crc;
}
```

The code works fine until `2694` bytes are read from the FLASH. Viewing `Memory` in the debugging session, I make sure that the next byte in the FLASH has value of `0C`. Checking the value of `ptr`, I make sure it has the address of this `0C` byte in the FLASH (which is 0x8B15). However, `value` variable always get the value of `8B` instead of `0C` after `ptr` is dereferenced.

I also tried to exclude unnecessary variables so it be like this:

```
crc = (crc >> 8) ^ table[(crc & 0xFF) ^ buf[index]];
```

But the table index was not as it should be as the memory location was read as `8B` instead of `0C`.

I found that the byte before and the byte after address `0x8B15` are read correctly. Only this address is read wrongly.

**UPDATE-1**

The disassembly of the `value = *ptr;` is as following:

```
LDW X, (0x11,SP)
LD  A, (X)
LD  (0x13,SP),A
```

When reading the byte at address `0x8B15`, if I put a breakpoint at the second assembly line and then the value in the memory location is read correctly as `0C`. However, if I put the breakpoint at the third assembly line instead, I find that register `X` has `0x8B15` (the right address) but register `A` has `0x8B` (the wrong value).

**UPDATE-2**

I added an `if` statement inside the `for` loop for debugging (to put my breakpoint). I found that the code saved in memory byte which is read wrongly is always the code inside this `if` statement. The disassembly of this code always have something to do with `SP`. Even if I changed the code, the problematic memory byte is always the first instruction in the `if` statement. And I also noticed that the wrong read value is always `0x8B` regardless what is the right value. Here is the disassembly saved in this memory location:

```
0x8b15 <crc32_buffer+104>   0x0C01 INC   (0x01,SP)  INC   (_CRC_ONGOING_s,SP)
```

Comment: maybe unrelated but you may want to declare `const uint8_t *ptr = buf;`, to get rid of the warning.

Comment: One of your screenshots mentions `unsigned char near *`.  Is this actually a segmented architecture?  near pointers can't cross segment boundaries, so that might have something to do with your problem.

Comment: @SteveSummit Could you please explain more what you mean?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are right, I should add `const`. It's `value` after xoring. Does it make a difference if it's before of after xoring?

Comment: no, my bad. it doesn't matter

Comment: It depends on the optimization level: If both variables are mapped into the same space (like a register) you'd see this behavior. The compiler might have decided that the life time of `value` ends after reading it for the XOR. You might like to check the generated machine code. But this wont explain your second observation with the "compressed" expression.

Comment: Something trivial but just in case if it is nand flash then read will be block based while code is reading byte by byte.

Comment: In you "update" your write about an address of 0x87F5, but the register X has the value of 0x887F5. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad.

Comment: How did you program the flash ? Is it possible that some bytes have not been properly programmed (because of a software bug of a flash driver for example) ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I build the project using STVD IDE then I run an external program on the PC which calculates the CRC for the S19 file and writes the calculated CRC in the S19 itself. Then I use a programmer tool from ST to read the S19 file and download it on the microcontroller. Finally, I start debugging using STVD IDE (I debug without reprogramming the microcontroller).

Comment: One potential problem is that you didn't `volatile` qualify the access, meaning you could experience optimization hiccups. More likely though, is a plain stack overflow. 32 bit arithmetic is very cumbersome for a STM8, it will have to use various software libs that takes lots of time and probably a fair bit of stack. What you should do first of all when the bug hits is to check the stack pointer. Everything about this bug sounds like a stack overflow.

Comment: @SteveSummit It's a 8 bit MCU so `near` simply means 16 bit addresses, whereas `far` would mean expanded memory beyond 64kib. Accessed in some MCU-specific way, bank selection registers or similar.

Comment: @Lundin I checked the SP when the wrong byte is read and it was in range. For my uC, stack ranges between `0x17FF` and `0x1400` and in my case `SP = 0x17D8`. Also, I made sure that SP doesn't change before or after reading this specific byte. It's the same when reading bytes before and after.

Comment: I‘m out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: If not stack overflow, then maybe a memory corruption bug. Make sure to have all interrupts disabled and see if that changes anything. Oh, and always read the part errata.

Comment: In one of my trials, I made sure that the only existing ISR is not called while reading this byte. But I‘ll try completely disabling interrupts.

Comment: I tried disabling interrupts before reading and the re-enabling them but this didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: If there is indeed no exception and your analysis is correct regarding the assemby code ("However, if I put the breakpoint at the third assembly line instead, I find that register X has 0x8B15 (the right address) but register A has 0x8B (the wrong value).") it's really weird and not linked to stack or to the C code. At what address your CRC code is executing ? May be there is a conflict between executing and reading the Flash ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Yes, I noticed that many times the problem happens in the memory address where the executing code itself is stored in (as I wrote in Update-2)

Comment: OK I didn't understand your comment. I bet there is a conflict in the Flash: you are executing and reading at the same address in parallel. I would not be surprised that it is not supported by the MCU. You can try to calculate CRC on a different memory area than the CRC function.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Sorry could you please explain more? I think the code should be the same and doesn't change during the project's lifetime. Regardless if it is being read or not. I noticed that the memory location which is read wrongly is the location that saves the `if-statement` in the code posted in the question. Every time I change the code but keep this if statement, the new location which saves the `if-statement` is read wrongly. When I tried to completely delete this `if-statement`, I found that another memory location - which is not in CRC calculation function - is read wrongly.

Comment: STM8 has an Harvard architecture, meaning that access to instruction and data is done through 2 separate buses. Here, both I and D buses try to access the same address, so may be it is not supported by the architecture ? It is just an hypothesis. Generally speaking, I think it is not very clean to do that (some software is reading itself). Usually you would have some kind of bootloader (or kernel or whatever you call it) checking the rest of the software.

Comment: @Guillaume There are microcontrollers behaving as described. But the STM8 family simply stalls its pipeline until the memory bus becomes available, according to its programming manual.

Comment: @Salahuddin Would you mind to check the opcode of `LD A,(X)`, please? The programming manual shows a value of 0xF6 without 0x90 before it. It is strange that A has 0x8B after executing it, which is the upper byte of the address in X. This could be done by `LD A,XH` with an opcode of 0x9E.

Comment: I think I solved it. Thanks to @GuillaumePetitjean I tried to store the code of the function that calculates CRC in a seperate special memory section instead of `.text` using `#pragma`. It worked the first time and the calculated CRC matched the expected one. Then when I tried it again the problem appeared again. So I placed the code in the whole CRC module (i.e., source file) in that special memory section. And it worked. I can't believe it did.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue last week .. It seems to be a problem with the debugging Firmware and your code both accessing the same location. If you have an active breakpoint at that same Flash location you are trying to read with your code, then your code ends up reading 0x8B from that location. If you remove or deactivate all breakpoints, the location is read correctly..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my previous answer (see above or below ..I couldn't edit that one).. Active breakpoints substitute the existing instruction at that particular Flash memory location with a BREAK instruction (opcode 0x8B), so when that memory location is read from within the application code, 0x8B will be the result.
So this is not really a 'problem', but rather a limitation of software breakpoints as implemented within the SWIM debugging firmware on the STM8S.